# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{6} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{4}  \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{6} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}  \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4} $?

In my opinion, this statement is correct because the maximal order of element in each side is $12$, but is it enough to prove it by stating it?

In general, should I show a specific isomorphism between the groups? If I should, how do I find one?

Comment: The answer is that yes, they are isomorphic, but **not** for the reason you claim. It is not enough to check what the maximal order of elements of each side is, even if both groups have the same size. For example, $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ both have order $16$, both have maximal order of elements equal to $4$, but they are *not* isomorphic. For finitely generated abelian groups, there are "normal forms": standard ways of writing the groups that determine whether two are isomorphic or not.

Comment: In this case, the two standard ways of writing the groups are $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ (as you write it on the right hand side; the primary divisor decomposition), or as $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ (the invariant factor decomposition). The left hand side is isomorphic to the right hand side because $\mathbb{Z}_6\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $gcd(2,3) = 1$, we have that $$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus\mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$$ and so the claim follows.

The fact that the maximal order of an element of two groups is equal is not sufficient to show that they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but my thought process tends towards "an isomorphism between any two structures is an invertible homomorphism".

Since the function $X\oplus Y\mapsto Y\oplus X$ is trivially an isomporphism, you really only need to determine if $\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3\cong\Bbb{Z}_6$, since the rest follows from $X \oplus Y \cong W \implies X\oplus Y \oplus Z\cong W \oplus Z$. It suffices to show that a homomorphism $f:\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3\to\Bbb{Z}_6$ is invertible.

While there are certainly much better methods for any particular example (including this one, see answers and comments), this is the only method I can think of which might work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Page 166, Chapter 8 Corollary 2, Contemporary Abstract Algebra, 8th ed. Joseph A. Gallian

> Let m = n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>.....n<sub>k</sub>. Then $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>m</sub> is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>n<sub>1</sub></sub> $\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>n<sub>2</sub></sub>$\oplus$....$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>n<sub>k</sub></sub> if and only if n<sub>i</sub> and n<sub>j</sub> are relatively prime when i $\ne$ j.

So, $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>6</sub> $\approx$ $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>2</sub>$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>3</sub> as 2 and 3 are relatively prime.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>4</sub>$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>6</sub> $\approx$ $\mathbb{Z}$<sub>2</sub>$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>3</sub>$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$<sub>4</sub>